# What is the recommended way to convert between pixels and points in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, pixel-density

I want to display a QR code in SwiftUI. The code is generated as a `CGImage` via `CIImage`. I don't want to scale it to the full size available because if the scaling factor isn't an integer there may be fuzzy boundaries between the QR modules. So I need a way to convert between iOS display points which I can get with `GeometryReader` and physical points. I've found a few search "hits" about reading the screen scale from a `UIView`, but not how I can get this scale in SwiftUI.

There a few more hits which just say the scale is 3 on all modern iPhones, and as I'm targeting iOS 15+ I think I can safely assume it's always 3 for now, but what if Apple bring out even higher pixel densities in future?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get [`displayScale`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues) using the [`Environment`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environment#) property wrapper.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.displayScale) var displayScale

    var body: some View {
        Text("display scale: \(displayScale)")
    }
}
```

Consult [`EnvironmentValues`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues#) to see what else SwiftUI provides in the “environment”.

Comment: Thanks. I just found displayScale myself by accident and came back here to add my own answer, but found you'd got there first. Weird how it was so hard to find the answer.